# Dual Booting Win10 with Ubuntu23.04?

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I want to dual-boot Windows 10 or 11 with my current OS Ubuntu 23.04. I tried to search on YouTube but I only found videos of dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows.
If there is any video on YouTube you can send the link too.....

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.